# use chrome extension to pass html of page to script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What I am trying to do, is have a chrome extension that grabs the HTML of the page I am currently on, and passes that whole thing as a string to the script so I can run a regex and replace on the whole page.

The whole script thing I can manage fine, but I am unsure about grabbing the whole page HTML and passing it as a string to the script, from what I understand, I should be looking in the direction of content scripts.

Any further advice would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use javascript to modify page DOM rather than modify it as a string using regex'es (it's just inefficient and error-prone). And, as you mentioned, this is achieved by content scripts.